# Foreach NodeList Enumerator in biml

Tags: ssis, nodelist, foreach-loop-container, biml

i have a foreach loop which traverse through the xml.
i know how to add this kind of foreach in SSIS. but not able to find the code snippet of **biml** for the same.

how to mentioned below properties in foreachloopcontainer in biml

> Enumerator= Foreach NodeList Enumerator
>
> DocumentSourceType=Variable
>
> DocumentSource
>
> EnumerationType = NodeText
>
> OuterXPathStringSourceType= DirectInput
>
> OuterXPathString = /ROOT/*

**any help in having sample code for writing foreachloopcontainer with nodelist enumerator would be a greate help!!!**

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use a variable as your input source, then you're looking for `VariableInput`

`EnumerationType` is exposed in the `ForEachNodeListLoop`

`DirectOuterXPath` is where you specify your OuterXPathStringSource, like `<DirectOuterXPath>/ROOT/*</DirectOuterXPath>`

While not an exact representation of your request (I use Variables across the board), to shred`<Files><File>Foo.txt</File><File>Bar.txt</File><File>Blee.txt</File></Files>` into Foo.txt, Bar.txt and Blee.txt

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="so_36759813">
            <Variables>
                <Variable DataType="String" Name="CurrentNode"></Variable>
                <Variable DataType="String" Name="SourceXML"><![CDATA[<Files><File>Foo.txt</File><File>Bar.txt</File><File>Blee.txt</File></Files>]]></Variable>
                <Variable DataType="String" Name="OuterXPath"><![CDATA[/Files/File]]></Variable>
                <Variable DataType="String" Name="InnerXPath"><![CDATA[.]]></Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <ForEachNodeListLoop 
                    Name="FENLL Shred XML"
                    EnumerationType="ElementCollection"
                    InnerElementType="NodeText"
                    >
                    <VariableInput VariableName="User.SourceXML" />
                    <VariableOuterXPath VariableName="User.OuterXPath" />
                    <VariableInnerXPath VariableName="User.InnerXPath" />
                    <VariableMappings>
                        <VariableMapping VariableName="User.CurrentNode" Name="0" />
                    </VariableMappings>
                    <Tasks>
                        <Script ProjectCoreName="ST_EchoBack" Name="SCR Echo Back">
                            <ScriptTaskProjectReference ScriptTaskProjectName="ST_EchoBack" />
                        </Script>            
                    </Tasks>
                </ForEachNodeListLoop>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
    <ScriptProjects>
        <ScriptTaskProject ProjectCoreName="ST_EchoBack" Name="ST_EchoBack" VstaMajorVersion="0">
            <ReadOnlyVariables>
                <Variable Namespace="User" VariableName="CurrentNode" DataType="String" />
            </ReadOnlyVariables>
            <Files>
                <File Path="ScriptMain.cs" BuildAction="Compile">using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_EchoBack
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            bool fireAgain = false;
            string message = "{0}::{1} : {2}";
            foreach (var item in Dts.Variables)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "SCR Echo Back", string.Format(message, item.Namespace, item.Name, item.Value), string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
    }
}                </File>
                <File Path="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" BuildAction="Compile">
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
                </File>
            </Files>
            <AssemblyReferences>
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Data" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Windows.Forms" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Xml" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll" />
                <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll" />
            </AssemblyReferences>
        </ScriptTaskProject>
    </ScriptProjects>
</Biml>
```